# How do I fix this copy and paste problem between Workbooks in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have what I think is a very simple issue, unfortunately I only have a basic understanding of VBA at this point.

I am trying to very simply copy and paste a range of data from the last row of data from a sheet from one Workbook, in to the next blank row in a sheet from another Workbook (screenshots of tables provided below). This then repeats for several sheets where the sheet names match across both Workbooks (hopefully the code makes more sense than that explanation). The code has been slightly adapted as I use it for many slightly different tables and scripts but for the same purpose.

```
Sub Hellotheregeneralkenobi()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("CallArrivals.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Online")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Online")

             'Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws1.Range("d26:L26").Copy
    ws2.Range("C" & Last_Row2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

However, when I execute this macro for the ***first*** time and ***only*** in the very first sheet (in this example called "Online"), it pastes the wrong selection of data (see error table screenshot below). But when I manually delete this pasted data and run the code again, everything works perfectly and the correct data is copied over (as shown in the table screenshots.

What is going on here? I am 100% sure I am just being stupid and missing something incredibly basic here. Unfortunately I am the only one of my team who has any coding experience at all (SQL).

Table showing the error:

[image: Screenshot showing the error]

Table showing it working after executing the second time:

[image]

Table showing where it's being copied from:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Screenshot of Table Showing Copied Data
[Edit: Screenshot of Table Showing Copied Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf6iR.png)

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook` to the name of the one you're on, that should help

Comment: Also, you have an unqualified `Rows` reference in your `Last_Row2` computation.  I think it should be `ws2.Rows`.

Comment: As per @Badja comment: please read up on dangers of using `ActiveWorkbook`. Active workbook could be any workbook at a given time which isn't necessarily the workbook you want to reference. There are always exception to the rule but as good coding practice, always reference the workbook/worksheet you want to interact with. Another good practice would be to try and do copy and paste in the same row (i.e. `<myRange>.Copy <myDestination>`). This is because when you do it in 2 separate lines, you start using clipboard. This might be ok for small data, but with large data set it can cause problems

Comment: @Badja Hi, thanks for the help. Ahh, so I have to exactly reference the Workbook I'm copying to, to prevent this issue? The problem is, every month I will be using a different Workbook with a different name. Yeah, I know 'ActiveWorkbook' has its limitations I just wasn't sure of a work around, so in this case I just quickly use MsgBox to just make sure that this specific Workbook is selected.

Comment: @cxw Hi, thanks for the help. I will take a look at this, cheers!

Comment: @Zac Hi, thanks for the help. Please look at my response to Badja. Oh right I see, I will definitely keep this in mind when working with larger data sets. Thanks!

Comment: If you will only have the 2 workbooks open when you run your code, you can loop through the workbooks and set `wb2` to the workbook which is not **CallArrivals**. This will make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Ref mine and MasterWu's comments - this should work for you (untested)

```
Sub Hellotheregeneralkenobi()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("CallArrivals.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("") 'The name of your workbook you are copying to - maybe use sourceWB and destWB instead of wb1 and wb2
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Online")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Online")

             'Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws1.Range("d26:L26").Copy _
        Destination:=ws2.Range("C" & Last_Row2)

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Badja I have made the change:  Set wb2 = Workbooks("Monthly Totals.xlsm") However, I am still having the same problem, where it copies the incorrect data the first time I run it and only on the first sheet (it repeats for other sheets correctly). And again, if I manually deleted the copied data and run the macro a second time, it works correctly. I'm baffled, it seems like a bug? I forgot to mention I am using Excel for Mac, Version 16.16.8, I think known for being not so good haha.

Comment: F8 through the sub, while looking at the destination sheet. Is it at the `ws1.Range(` line that the wrong data is copied?

Comment: @Badja unqualified `Rows` reference

Comment: @Badja Sorry about the delay in response over the weekend. Yes, it's at `ws1.Range("D26:G26").Copy` that it copies the wrong data. Let me see if I can edit my post and include a new screenshot. Thanks for all the help btw!